# Regarding regular expression. why do the following strings not exist in the expression.

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Let L be the language defined by the regular expression:

(a U b U c)((ab U ac U b)*(a U b) U (aa)*)

the answer book says that 'aaaa' and 'aaaaaa' do not belong to L.
I can show that aaaa and aaaaaa is deducable using the reg exp per above:

aaaa:

a U b U c -> a

ab U ac U b -> empty string

a U b -> a

(aa)* -> aa

so aaaa

for aaaaaa:

a U b U c -> a

ab U ac U b -> empty string

a U b -> a

(aa)* -> aaaa

so, aaaaaa

Am i doing something wrong here?
thank you.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: If you take $ab+ac+b \mapsto \varepsilon$ and $a+b \mapsto a$ you obtain $a$. Then you take $(aa)^\ast \mapsto aa$ and then you must choose either $a$, or $aa$ (not both)

Comment: @user35603: Oops: I missed the outer set of parentheses. (So, apparently, did three other people.) Do you want to write an answer explaining what’s going on, or shall I?

Comment: @user35603, per your statement: "Then you take (aa)∗↦aa and then you must choose either a, or aa (not both)" why can't u choose both? it's (a U (aa)*) isn't it? so can't u choose both?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Maybe you :)

Comment: @user35603: Okay; I’m doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression is a concatenation of $a\cup b\cup c$ and $(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*(a\cup b)\cup (aa)^*$, so after you take $a$ from $a\cup b\cup c$, you must choose **either** from $(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*$ **or** from $(aa)^*$; you can’t use both, because they’re alternatives within the expression $$(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*(a\cup b)\cup (aa)^*\;.$$ (In my original comment, now deleted, I missed the parentheses around $$(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*(a\cup b)\cup (aa)^*\;,$$ reading the expression as $(a\cup b\cup c)(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*(a\cup b)\cup(aa)^*$, a union (or disjunction) of two expressions rather than as a concatenation.)

If you choose from $(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*$, you clearly won’t get all $a$’s, so you must choose from $(aa)^*$. That gives you $2n$ $a$’s for some $n\ge 0$, so together with the initial $a$ from $a\cup b\cup c$ you have $a^{2n+1}$. In other words, if you generate a string of $a$’s, it necessarily contains an odd number of $a$’s.

You can also see this by ‘multiplying out’ the original regular expression. You get a union (or disjunction) of the following terms:

$$\begin{align*}
&a(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*a\\
&a(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*b\\
&b(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*a\\
&b(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*b\\
&c(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*a\\
&c(ab\cup ac\cup b)^*b\\
&a(aa)^*\\
&b(aa)^*\\
&c(aa)^*
\end{align*}$$

The only one of these that generates all $a$’s is $a(aa)^*$, which always generates an odd number of $a$’s.